# Assign PHP variable only once throughout application

Tags: php

I have a php file(ext.php) which has the PHP code as:

```
<?php
      $i = 0;
      while($i < 1000){    
         echo $i;
         ob_flush();
         flush();
         sleep(1);
         $i++;

     }
?>
```

I have to include ext.php into my application's index.php, my consideration is:

**$i should be assigned with 0 only once through application**

Comment: Does this mean it's currently assigned more than once? You would have to include it more than once for that to happen, but you don't mention anything about multiple includes.

Comment: I have to assign only once, but I could include more than once.

Answer (score 0):

You mean once in execution or one even if you have multiple requests? You can use include_once.php for execution problem, or save `$i` in session for multiple requests problem.